# python dictionaries and items()

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

My understanding is that .items() is only avaliable for python dictionaries.

However in the following bit of code, which runs perfectly, it appears that the .items() function is avaliable for a string. (This code is for the preprocessing stage of doc2vec )

I have looked at this for a while and I can't figure out why the .items() seems to work in this piece of code.

In the code, 'sources' is just an attribute of an instance. Yet it is able to call .items().

What am I missing here?

```
class LabeledLineSentence(object):

    def __init__(self, sources):
        self.sources = sources

        flipped = {}

        # make sure that keys are unique
        for key, value in sources.items():
            if value not in flipped:
                flipped[value] = [key]
            else:
                raise Exception('Non-unique prefix encountered')
```

Comment: There is nothing in the code shown to imply that `sources` (and hence `self.sources`) is anything other than a `dict`-like object. Why do you think it's a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given code only specifies that sources is an attribute of an instance. It doesn't specify its type. In fact it can be any type that is specified at the time of creating an instance of LabeledLineSentence.

```
i1 = LabeledLineSentence('sample text') # sources is now a string. Throws error!
i2 = LabeledLineSentence({}) # source is a now a dictionary. No error!
```

Note that LabeledLineSentence implementation expects the sources parameter to be a dictionary.

Comment: thanks for the answer Jayson :) I am just a beginner and answers like yours saves me a lot of time. In all of the youtube python vids I have watched, none of them mention anything about specifying the type of the instance at the time of creation. They just pass in arguments and that is it. These things are so time consuming for beginners to figure out because I am not even aware of such things. Thanks again, looks like I need to hit the beginner python books again. :) :)

Comment: If you are looking for books I recommend the "python crash course" for a beginner. Once the fundamentals are clear, you can then check out books such as "effective python" or "fluent python"

Answer (score 0):

.items() is available for any class with an items method. For instance, I can define

```
class MyClass:
    def items(self):
        return [1,2,3,4]
```

and then run

```
mc = MyClass()
for i in mc.items(): print(i)
```

Presumably your `sources` object is of a class that has such an attribute. But we don't know what, since it's an argument to the constructor of `LabeledLineSentence`.

Can you point us to the full source code? Then we might be able to see what is being passed in.